# Xamarin on Mac: Unable to detect my android device

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, adb

I'm trying to connect my Samsung S6 Edge to my Mac to debug my Xamarin android application. For some reason it's not able to detect it. The device gets detected on other Macs but only on my mac laptop it is unable to detect it.

I'm not sure if I blacklisted this one specific laptop on my android device. Can anyone please advice, how can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Do you have the usb drivers installed on your mac for the S6 edge?

Comment: Mac usually don't need any drivers for adb. You just need to make sure developer debugging is enabled.

Comment: I didn't install any usb drivers, same devices gets detected on other Macs but it doesn't get detected on one specific laptop. When I connect it charges so I know it knows the  external device being plugged in. In my developer options, usb is turned on and usb config is set to MTP.

Comment: Sometimes to trigger detection I turn off usb-debugging on the device, wait 10 seconds and turn it back on. Revoking all USB debugging authorisations sometimes fixes it for me. Do you see the device connected on the mac and Xamarin studio doesn't see it or it's not detected at all?

Comment: I resolved it. I just had to switch the USB wire.